# Loading Data From Comma Separated Text File to 2D Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d, double

I am trying to load data from a text file that looks like this:

161,77,88,255
0,44,33,11,111

etc. I have functions to manipulate it, and am ensured that the array is the correct size (which may still vary). Below is my attempt at implementation:

```
bool loadData(int **imgPix, string fileName) {

ifstream inputFile;

inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

string tempLineRow; //The resulting line from the text file
string tempElementColumn; //The individual integer element 
int numberOfCols = 0;
int numberOfRows = 0;


if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
    return false;
}

imgPix = new int* [numberOfRows];

    while (getline(inputFile, tempLineRow, '\n')) {

        stringstream ss; 
        ss << tempLineRow; //Stringstream version of the line

        while (getline(ss, tempElementColumn, ',' )) {
            stringstream ss2; 
            ss2 << tempElementColumn;
            ss2 >> numberOfCols;

//Prob?         (**imgPix) = *(*(imgPix + numberOfRows) + numberOfCols);
            numberOfCols++;

        }

        numberOfRows++;

    }   

inputFile.close();
return true;
```

}

I've marked the line with the double pointer assignment with a comment, because I believe it be the source of my error, although there could be others. I'm not sure how to use the while loop structure I've implemented to iteratively update the 2D array.

Can anyone offer any assistance? Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imgPix = new int* [numberOfRows]
```

Here numberOfRows = 0, so you don't allocate enough memory. You need to know dimensions of the array before you allocate the memory.
And then you should also allocate a memory for each row in the array:

```
imgPix[currentRow] = new int [TotalCols];
```

For a 2-dimensional rectangular array, it would be more efficient to create 1-dimensional array of TotalRows*TotalCols elements, and then access it using formula `A(row, col) = A[row*TotalCols + col]`.

Comment: 100% correct, but the crucial point is "one needs to know dimensions beforehand", so I guess this approach leads to a dead end. Use of std::vector would make things a hell lot easier to handle for the OP.

Comment: Yes, using `std::vector` is easier and more elegant. Well, `vector` of `vector`s looks to me an overhead, but probably the performance is not important here. In any case, he needs to know at least one (inner) dimension of the array beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues, mostly I guess because you did not fully understand how built-in arrays work in C++. The main issue here is that those cannot easily grow dynamically, there is no "resize" operation for those arrays (but you will need one here). So I suggest kindly that you try to rewrite your code using `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`, make sure you use of `.resize` when you store a new row or column and come back and ask again when you run into problems with this new implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are valid, but if contiguous memory is not a requirement, `std::deque`s may be a better choice in this case compared to `std::vector`s to avoid lots of memory reallocations.